# changing orientation in Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm tryin to change the orientation of the *Bootstrap Datetimepicker* I even tried with [this](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?#sandbox) but I get:

```
option orientation is not recognized
```

My definition of the datetimepicker in the html is:

```
<div class='input-group date datepicker' name="datepicker">
    <input type='text' class="form-control placementT" id="fecha">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
               </span>
         </span>
</div>
```

In the javascript I have something like this to change the language:

```
$('.input-group.date').datetimepicker({
            locale: "es",
        });
```

I tried adding `location:'bottom auto'` but nothing happens.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "orientation"? If you use an [option](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html) that's not supported then you should expect errors.

Comment: @Jasen I want that the datepicker always open down the input, and never in the top of the input. by default the datetimepicker have _auto_ in that property and sometimes opens down or up. I want this always down

Comment: You could try to recompute its `top` and `left` in the `show()` event. You'll also have to adjust its `datepicker-orient-*` classes. But you might want to search for a different plug-in that will give you the option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reading a lot of post, and the documentation, I made it! for future visitors, can read all the available option [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#dayviewheaderformat) and for this specific example, I made:

```
 $('.input-group.date').datetimepicker({
            widgetPositioning:{
                                horizontal: 'auto',
                                vertical: 'bottom'
                            }
        });
```

Now, all the time I have the datetimepicker in the bottom of the input, and this is just what I wanted.